# schema element in @Table Annotion

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm actually revising hibernate & JPA, which I came across the @Table annotation and its usage. We've 'schema' element as part of that annotation. I was trying to figure does this schema is something to do with different data sources that we supposedly want to configure our application with or just a identifier where the query has to be executed.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Database can have multiple schemas, and each can hold the same table name in them. I wouldn't define the schema in the entity definition unless you had a strong requirement to do so - defining it in the entity makes it harder to have a testing schema and dev testing schema in the same DB and point the app at different ones if/when appropriate for testing - something easily configured on the datasource.

Comment: @Chris, I want to know the usage of schema element if I have multiple datasources where the entities won't belong to single datasource. In this case, does this element will make us differentiate the datasource and knows which to query out?

Comment: I may be daft, but still don't understand the question as schema has nothing to do with datasources. The table annotation on entities tells your JPA provider how to build the queries, not where to execute them. If you have a schema and table defined, it'll form queries of the form 'SELECT a, b, c FROM schema.table' and issue it through what ever datasource is defined for the context you are using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.